# Importing from Excel to a Calendar

Tags: import

I have a new calendar that currently has no events on it. There is a calendar on one of my other sharepoint sites that I'd like to copy all the events in it over to this new one. I've exported all the calendar data to an excel file (saved as a .iqy), but I don't see any way to import the data. I read you have to simply click the 'import' button, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Please specify your SharePoint tenants.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Sharepoint 2016.

Comment: Did you get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint doesn’t offer a command or a tool that allows users to bulk add events into a calendar; but by using Office apps (**Excel and Access**) we can do that very easily.

Kindly check the below mentioned article for your reference. It will work same in SharePoint 2016.

[SharePoint: How to Add Events into a Calendar Using Microsoft Excel and Access](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/09/24/sharepoint-how-to-add-events-into-a-calendar-using-microsoft-excel-and-access-aspx/)

Comment: This worked. Thank you! But I tried to color code them by adding new "calendars in view", but it couldn't resolve the web URL...

Comment: You can create it by your own, in new site where you have moved your calendar.

Comment: Create what on my own?

Comment: Color coded views of calendar

Comment: This link is dead. Please, in future, put the relevant info within the answer and not just a link.